# How can I restrict the access of an action or URL in Java Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I have a Java Spring app and I want that when a user is on a page of the app that another user can not access it and show him an informative message.

This is because I have a form that users must edit every day, so if two users enter the same form at the same time, they will see the initial data, but then when one saves and the other also, the data will be overwritten. of the first save.

Comment: For stuff like this, optimistic locking in Hibernate should be used. This provides a version for an entity, and if the current user stores the entity, the version is incremented, whereas the other user cannot store the "old" version.
See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch05.html

Comment: It is a good idea, but you would not show the error until you click save, having to waste time filling in the form

Comment: Sure, that all depends on your use-case. Your solution could lack some stuff as well, like what happens if the first user is not doing anything while on the page? What happens, if there is an error during storeage and the semaphore is not removed, so all other users can still not access this page?

Comment: Yes, you are right, but maybe there is some spring annotation that allows me to do this without having to touch the database.

Comment: Even if there is an "annotation" (which i doubt) for this, you would still be able to store this kinda semaphore somewhere (database, file-system, ...).